# how to save pcm audio buffer as acc or other audio file?

Tags: iphone

I get pcm audio from http protocol and i can play it.However, I don't know how to save them as ACC or other audio file.
Does anybody can help me?thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Audio File Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006072) and the [Audio File Stream Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioStreamReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006162) in the SDK. A readymade project for encoding to AAC can be [found over at github](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPAACAudioConverter).